# Wrap every 2 divs in a new div

Tags: jquery, html

Say I have this:

```
<div class="somediv"></div>
<div class="somediv"></div>
<div class="somediv"></div>
<div class="somediv"></div>
<div class="somediv"></div>
<div class="somediv"></div>
```

How would I wrap every 2 divs in a new div with a class of "newdiv" ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's how to do it:

```
var elems = $(".somediv"),
wrapper = $('<div class="wrapper" />');
for (var i = 0;i < elems.length;i+=2){
    elems.filter(':eq('+i+'),:eq('+(i+1)+')').wrapAll(wrapper);
};
```

A working [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/r5M5Q/2/)

Comment: Works great, thanks! I started with a ul actually, and worked my way towards making the li tags div tags with the same class, but this I couldn't do (especially looking at the code now), so I think your pun is out of place but thanks anyway.

Comment: Just saying that it helps when you write down the things you already tried, like you did just now ;) good luck with it

Comment: @c_kick won't the line `var wrapper = $('<div id="wrapper" />');` cause multiple divs with the same id?

Comment: I'd mark this answer up if it weren't for the first sentence or the id thing.