# Jquery wrap content that has group size variants

Tags: jquery

Im new to jquery but I’m looking to create some kind of iteration loop that will wrap some divs in an external parent wrapper so that I can use it to arrange some images more creatively.

What I’m trying to get is something that would work like this:

```
<div class=“wrap_row_1”>
    <div> Image file </div>
</div>

<div class=“wrap_row_2”>
   <div> Image file </div>
   <div> Image file </div>
   <div> Image file </div>
</div>

<div class=“wrap_row_3”>
   <div> Image file </div>
   <div> Image file </div>
</div>
```

I did some digging around for a possible solution and came across this but it isn’t exactly how I need it to work with my situation.

[Wrap every 2 divs in a new div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13489450/wrap-every-2-divs-in-a-new-div)

If anyone could guide me through how to achieve something like this - id be really thankful.

Comment: How do you decide in which wrapper to put a certain `div`? Is it random, or is there some logic? Could you be more specific?

Comment: @trincot I’m basically trying to create an Instagram feed that looks a lot like the desktop version of [this site](https://kentandcurwen.com).  Every few posts are wrapped in a parent so they can be controlled with css. This is what I’m looking to replicate.

Comment: So can you answer my question? What is the logic?

Comment: The logic is how it was originally asked and shown. The first post needs a wrap, the next 3 need a wrap, the last 2 need a wrap. That was it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you could put 6 elements (with a certain CSS class) in a 1 - 3 - 2 wrapped arrangement:

```js
var elems = $(".wrapthis");
var sizes = [1,3,2];
for (var row = 0; row < sizes.length; row++) {
    var wrapper = $("<div>").addClass("wrap_row_" + (row+1));
    $(elems.splice(0, sizes[row])).wrapAll(wrapper);
}
```

```css
.wrap_row_1 { border: 1px solid }
.wrap_row_2 { border: 1px solid; background: silver }
.wrap_row_3 { border: 1px solid }
.wrapthis { display: inline-block; margin: 5px }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapthis"> Image file 1</div>
<div class="wrapthis"> Image file 2</div>
<div class="wrapthis"> Image file 3</div>
<div class="wrapthis"> Image file 4</div>
<div class="wrapthis"> Image file 5</div>
<div class="wrapthis"> Image file 6</div>
```

Comment: Any results...?